# DBCC CHECKIDENT -- Schema aware?

Tags: sql-server, schema

I've got a different schema (besides dbo) that I've created a table in, schema "Chemical".

I've tried 4 different variations of this DBCC CHECKIDENT, and they all bring back the same error:

"Incorrect syntax near '.'"

I've tried:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (Chemical.[Products], RESEED, 0)

DBCC CHECKIDENT (Chemical.Products)

DBCC CHECKIDENT ([Chemical].[Products])

DBCC CHECKIDENT (Chemical.Products, RESEED, 0)
```

Is it schema aware or what am I missing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can surround with single quotes or inside square brackets. Both work.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Chemical.Products', RESEED, 0)
DBCC CHECKIDENT ([Chemical.Products], RESEED, 0)
```

Comment: This is so inconsistent with the rest of T-SQL. Why is it this way?

Comment: Single quote way worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try surrounding it in single quotes

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Chemical.Products', RESEED, 0)
```